# Elixir quote vs escape

Tags: macros, escaping, elixir, quote

When, in Elixir, should one use `Macro.escape/1` instead of `quote/1`? I've looked at the [beginner's guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html) and it's not helping.

Comment: There is no [`Kernel.escape/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/search.html?q=escape) in Elixir. One should use `quote` to get AST out of the source code.

Comment: He meant `Macro.escape/1`.

Comment: May i humbly suggest that if you're looking at the beginner's guide you might want to hold off on trying to use Elixir macros till you get a bit better grasp of the language?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I have a decent grasp of the language; the beginner's guide still provides more explanation than the rest of the docs. And given that it has a section on macros, your suggestion is a bit of a catch-22.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2) returns the [abstract syntax tree (AST)](https://dorgan.netlify.app/posts/2021/04/the_elixir_ast/) of the **passed in *code block***.

[`Macro.escape/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Macro.html#escape/2) returns the AST of the **passed in *value***.

Here is a example:

```
iex(1)> a = %{"apple": 12, "banana": 90}
%{apple: 12, banana: 90}

iex(2)> b = quote do: a
{:a, [], Elixir}

iex(3)> c = Macro.escape(a)
{:%{}, [], [apple: 12, banana: 90]}
```

[`quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2) will keep the origin variable `a`, while [`Macro.escape/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Macro.html#escape/2) will inject `a`'s value into the returned AST.

```
iex(4)> Macro.to_string(b) |> Code.eval_string

  warning: variable "a"  does  not exist and is being
  expanded to "a()", please use parentheses to remove
  the ambiguity or change the variable name
    nofile:1

iex(5)> Macro.to_string(c) |> Code.eval_string
{%{apple: 12, banana: 90}, []}

iex(6)> Macro.to_string(b) |> Code.eval_string([a: "testvalue"])
{"testvalue", [a: "testvalue"]}
```

---

For completeness' sake:

```
iex(1)> a = %{"apple": 12, "banana": 90}
%{apple: 12, banana: 90}

iex(3)> Macro.escape(a)
{:%{}, [], [apple: 12, banana: 90]}

iex(2)> quote do: %{"apple": 12, "banana": 90}
{:%{}, [], [apple: 12, banana: 90]}
```