# How to write a multiline `do` block with the `do:` atom syntax?

Tags: elixir

For example, how would this module definition look like on one line?

```
defmodule Lofa do
  def miez do
    IO.puts("hello")
    a = 27
    IO.puts("bye")
    a
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that one simply uses parentheses (`(`, `)`) around the block and semicolons (`;`) to separate the expressions:

```
defmodule Lofa, do: (def miez, do: (IO.puts("hello");a = 27;IO.puts("bye");a))
```

or taking it further:

```
iex(75)> defmodule(Lofa, [{:do, def(miez, [{:do, (IO.puts("hello"); a = 27; IO.puts("bye"); a)}])}])
```

#### Questions

The parentheses do not provide a lexical scope, it seems to be just for grouping:

```
iex(1)> a = :lofa                                                        
:lofa

iex(2)> (&(&1)).( (IO.puts("hello"); a = 27; IO.puts("bye"); a) )          
hello
bye
27

iex(3)> a
27
```

#### Related

- The [21. Optional syntax sheet](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/optional-syntax.html) chapter in the ["Getting Started" guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/) is exactly about this topic.
- [`quote/2` vs `Macro.escape/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804477/elixir-quote-vs-escape)
- [What are module and function names exactly? (they seem to be more than atoms)](https://elixirforum.com/t/what-are-module-and-function-names-exactly-they-seem-to-be-more-than-atoms/47632)
- [A deep dive into the Elixir AST (2021/04/16)](https://dorgan.netlify.app/posts/2021/04/the_elixir_ast/)